# Background image for a webpage

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm new for the ASP.NET. I need to know how to add a background image for my webpage?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with [CSS](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/cssbackgrounds.html), you don't need to do anything with ASP here.

Add the following code to your `Style.css` file and make sure you change the path to your background image to your real image.

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/myImage.png);
}
```

Now, no matter how many pages you have, you have your background image defined in only one place.  In the future, you can change the background image for all of your web pages (that reference your CSS file) by changing this one line.

Answer (score 0):

If its an image you want to be repeated horizontal of vertical,

you can use repeat-x or repeat-y

```
body {
background-image: url(images/photo1.png); 
background-repeat: repeat-y; 
}
```